# Snappy daemon and other apps not working after changing permissions

Tags: command-line

By mistake I ran

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw update
```

Is there a way to reverse that command?
Now snappy daemon is failing to start and other apps are not launching.
I believe it's from my mistake!

Comment: In which directory did you run the command? There is no way to revert changes made by chmod unless you know which permissions the affected files and folders had before issuing chmod.

Comment: desktop terminal

Comment: @Cougar _mook765_ wanted to know where in the filesystem you were when you entered that command. Had you just opened the terminal? Were you at ~/ your home directory, or in some other directory? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question.. Please so not click Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled and reinstalled snappy daemon!

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
sudo apt install snapd
```

Everything is working again!